# Using Puppeteer on Login Page after adding an item to cart

Tags: puppeteer

I'm working on a script to automate the purchasing of sneakers from Nike. I've been able to get the point where it adds the sneakers to the cart and go to the checkout page, which requires logging in. That's about the point where it all breaks.

I'm thinking it may have something to do with it being a completely separate page from the original target URL but I'm not sure.

Here's what I have so far...

```js
(async () => { 

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        headless: false,
        args: [
            '--disable-web-security'
        ],
        executablePath: '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome',
        userDataDir: '/Users/larry/Library/Application\ Support/Google\ Chrome'
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();   
    await page.goto(https://www.nike.com/launch/t/air-force-1-low-triple-white);
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }); // Wait for page to finish loading
    
    
    
    // ##################################################
    // ##################################################
    // ################################## ROUND 1
    // BEGIN
    
    await page.waitFor(500);
    
    // ##################################################
    // ##################################################
    // ################################## ROUND 2   
    // Wait for size selector to appear, then scroll to it
    
    await page.waitForSelector('.size-grid-dropdown');
    await page.evaluate(() =>
        document.querySelectorAll(".size-grid-dropdown")[0].scrollIntoView()
    );
    
    await page.waitFor(500);
    
    
    
    
    // ##################################################
    // ##################################################
    // ################################## ROUND 3
    // Pick my size from the options
    
    await page.evaluate(async(size) => {
        let sizes = await Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".size-grid-dropdown"));
        let sizeIndex = sizes
            .map((s, i) => (s.innerHTML === size ? i : false))
            .filter(Boolean)[0];
        return sizes[sizeIndex].click();
    }, size);
    
    await page.waitFor(500);
    
    
    // ##################################################
    // ##################################################
    // ################################## ROUND 4   
    // Wait for add to cart button, then scroll into view
    
    await page.waitForSelector('button[data-qa=add-to-cart]');
    await page.evaluate(() =>
        document.querySelectorAll("button[data-qa=add-to-cart]")[0].scrollIntoView()
    );
    
    await page.waitFor(500);
    

        // ##################################################
    // ##################################################
    // ################################## ROUND 5   
    // Click the add to cart button
    
    await page.evaluate(() =>
        document.querySelectorAll("button[data-qa=add-to-cart]")[0].click()
    );
    
    await page.waitFor(500);

        // ##################################################
    // ##################################################
    // ################################## ROUND 6   
    // Click the checkout button
    
    await page.waitForSelector('button[data-qa="checkout-link"]');
    await page.evaluate(() =>
        document.querySelectorAll("button[data-qa=checkout-link]")[0].click()
    );
    
    await page.waitFor(500);
    
    
    // ##################################################
    // ##################################################
    // ################################## ROUND 7
    // Login
    
    await page.waitForSelector('#nike-unite-loginForm');
    await page.waitFor(500);
    
    // Username
    await page.focus('input[type="email"]');
    await page.keyboard.type(user);
    await page.waitFor(200);
    
    // Password
    await page.focus('input[type="password"]')
    await page.keyboard.type(pass);
    await page.waitFor(200);
    
    // Submit
    await page.evaluate(() =>
        document.querySelectorAll('button[value="MEMBER CHECKOUT"]')[0].click()
    );
```

**So the problem is that once you get to Round 7, you get to the login screen but nothing happens.**

Here's the error that gets generated

```
(node:1488) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.
    at rewriteError (/Volumes/Nike/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:261:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (/Volumes/Nike/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:215:61)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (/Volumes/Nike/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:106:16)
    at async DOMWorld.content (/Volumes/Nike/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/DOMWorld.js:115:16)
    at async Page.content (/Volumes/Nike/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:820:16)
    at async /Volumes/Nike/bot.js:214:10
(node:1488) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1488) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: You need to be much more specific: how it goes wrong? what errors are can be seen? what exact part of code is not working well? Currently the question has too little info and code is too big for us to be able to help you

Comment: @Vaviloff Good point. I've updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Great! Now take this error: `Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation`, google it, and start reading what is found, deciding if it fits your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to click the specific size then add to cart and go through all that.

All you need to do is load up Nikes pre-cart. This works for any type of drop too.

You need to get the productID off the page or you can enter it before the drop and get the size you want.

Then you just load this URL:

> "{SNKRS_URL}?size={size}&productId={product_id)"

This should load up a pre-cart where you can enter all your details then submit.

Comment: for some reason, recently this method doesn't work on nike anymore. is there an alternative solution to load up pre-cart?